# How Can I Access a Service in my Angular NGRX Selector

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngrx

In my Angular app I have a Selector file `plan.selectors.ts` which has a few really complex Selectors. A lot of calculations are carried out when retrieving the data and some of these calculations are shared with business logic elsewhere in the application. Take a trivial example, I have a `DateService` which uses the `Moment` library and it provides functions to the application like `getDatePlusHours` where I can pass in a `Date` and a number of hours and it returns the new Date. I want to be able to use this function from my `DateService` in my Selector but I just cannot figure a way to do this as I can't see how to inject the Service in.

A simplified `plan.selectors.ts` looks like this with what I am trying to do:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

const getPlanFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<PlanState>('plan');

export const getStartDate = createSelector(
  state => state.startDate
);

export const getDuration = createSelector(
  state => state.duration
);

export const getEndDate = createSelector(
  getStartDate,
  getDuration,
  (startDate, duration) => {
    return dateService(startDate, duration);
  }
);
```

I'm trying to prevent duplicating huge amounts of Service functions into my Selector file. Any advice really welcome.

Comment: I think the pattern to use here is to call the service from wherever you are subscribing to the store, then pass the result as arguments to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in NGRX is that the selector only reads and sends a portion of the state, ie it does not perform any calculations or external services calls .
The calculations performing in the Reducer, and the external services calling in the Effect.
[Here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough) you can see an good example with full descripting.
Let me know if you need more details.